# данные из бд в лист

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как данные из определенного столбца таблицы преобразовать в лист

```
string sql = "select translation from dict_Table WHERE dictionary = '" + textBox_name.Text + "'";
```

И далее нужно добавить полученный лист к объекту `numbers`:

```
Choices numbers = new Choices();
numbers.Add(new string[] {...});
```

Comment: Разверните свой вопрос: из какого столбца (приведите модель сущности), что юзаете, может добавьте код, где вы пытались и тд...

Comment: Вроде, всё есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, если Вы используете `SqlConnection`:

```
string sql = "select translation from dict_Table WHERE dictionary = '" + textBox_name.Text + "'";
// список транзакций
List<string> transactions = new List<string>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();               
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                transactions.Add(reader["translation"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }            
}
...
Choices numbers = new Choices();
numbers.Add(transactions.ToArray())
```